# MVC Music Store Saving concurrency. What is causing this?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am doing the MVC Music Store Tutorials and I have finished, every works fine but for some reason when I edit an album on an Admin account it comes up with this error when I try to save changes. It highlights **db.SaveChanges();**     what is causing this problem?

Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. Refresh ObjectStateManager entries.

```
    public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        Album album = db.Albums.Find(id);
        ViewBag.GenreId = new SelectList(db.Genres, "GenreId", "Name", album.GenreId);
        ViewBag.ArtistId = new SelectList(db.Artists, "ArtistId", "Name", album.ArtistId);
        return View(album);
    }

    //
    // POST: /StoreManager/Edit/5

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(Album album)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(album).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        ViewBag.GenreId = new SelectList(db.Genres, "GenreId", "Name", album.GenreId);
        ViewBag.ArtistId = new SelectList(db.Artists, "ArtistId", "Name", album.ArtistId);
        return View(album);
    }
```

I am the only person accessing the site I have made as I am doing it locally only on my machine, I have been told that somebody else may changed something but this is not the case. What's going on?

Comment: Hi Jared, show your code from both Edit ActionResults

Comment: I've added it, let me know if you need to see any other code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This issue is explained on [this](http://mvcmusicstore.codeplex.com/workitem/6648) page on the musicstore codeplex site.

Here is an excerpt:

*In the Album class, you've defined [Bind(Exclude = "AlbumId")] on the class, which means that the code won't try and bind the AlbumId from the form. Which is fine, except that on the edit page, you're passing in a populated Album, which is presumably being populated using binding, which is of course ignoring the Album Id, so the AlbumId of the object passed into the edit method, is always 0, which throws a misleading concurrency error, because no rows are affected, because there's no album with ID of 0.*

Comment: No probs - just trying to up my answers versus questions ratio.